# Do videos uploaded via the YouTube API respect default monetization settings?

Tags: youtube-api

I experienced that with with Google-cl there is just no option to enable monetized content; imported from the command-line.

Is it even possible via api?

I set the default settings in youtube to monetize new content and via the youtube website manual uploaded content gets configured correctly. But using google-cl this setting is ignored.

Can someone point me in the right direction or is it just not possible?

I have 4 Videos per day which get uploaded and don't want to edit everyone by hand.

Comment: I've edited your title to make it clear that this has to do with videos uploaded via the YouTube API (which is what google-cl uses).

Answer (score 3):

Videos uploaded via the YouTube Data API (which is what [google-cl](https://code.google.com/p/googlecl/) uses under the hood) should ideally respect the default settings in your account for new videos.

I'll follow up internally to see if there's any reason why you're not seeing that happen in practice.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. This is more then i would have imagined. My next question is of course how do i notice if something has changed. Will you update this post or do i just see it working. Thanks for the great support already. J.

Comment: The YouTube API team plans on adding support for default settings in YouTube Data API v3 uploads at some point in the future, but unfortunately it's not something that can be supported at this time. There's information on keeping up to date on new functionality at http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/02/keeping-up-with-youtube-api-updates.html

Comment: It has been about a year and half since this answer. Do you happen to know if they have added this feature yet? I looked through the revision history of the Data API v3, but have not had any luck in finding an answer one way or the other.

Comment: @JeffPosnick was this implemented in v3?